# How to light the Caps Lock LED when in insert mode (on GNU/Linux)?

Tags: key-bindings, insert-mode

On Xubuntu LTS, I already managed to [remap <kbd>CapsLock</kbd> to <kbd>Esc</kbd>](https://askubuntu.com/a/758165/164341).

However, now I discovered some Vim users are [lighting the <kbd>Scroll Lock</kbd> LED](https://www.reddit.com/r/linux/comments/5p2w90/does_anyone_use_their_scroll_lock_light_for/), <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> LED or even the [entire keyboard](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7vlr74B3mDA) **to indicate that (g)Vim is in the insert mode.**

[image: Varmilo Caps Lock with LED]

Unfortunately, explanations about how to accomplish this Vim feat (under GNU/Linux) are nowhere to be found.

Can some good Vim soul show me the light?

## Fun fact

[Bill Joy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bill_Joy) developed `vi` from June through October 1977 on a [Lear Siegler ADM-3A terminal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ADM-3A). On this terminal, the <kbd>Esc</kbd> key was at the location now occupied by the <kbd>Tab</kbd> key on the IBM PC keyboard. This is somewhat the rationale behind converting the current IBM PC <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> into an <kbd>Esc</kbd> key.

[image: ADM-3A keyboard layout]

[image: The Lear Siegler ADM-3A terminal]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Caps Lock LED without `root` privileges

[image: Varmilo Caps Lock with LED]

### 1) Making <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> act like <kbd>Esc</kbd>

The full path to below `bash` script was added to `Session and Startup` → `Application Autostart` in Xubuntu LTS.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
sleep 4
xmodmap -e "clear Lock"
xmodmap -e "keysym Caps_Lock = Escape"
```

### 2) Edit `/usr/share/X11/xkb/compat/ledcaps`

```
$ sudo sed -i 's|\!allowExplicit|allowExplicit|g' /usr/share/X11/xkb/compat/ledcaps
```

**Logging out and in again** will allow these X settings to take effect.
For more information, [see here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/179378/39845).

### 3) Add an `augroup` to `$MYVIMRC`

In `$MYVIMRC` add the following:

```
" Light the Caps Lock LED when in Insert mode.
" https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/17824/3168
if has("gui_running")
    augroup CapsLockLED
        autocmd!
        autocmd InsertEnter * :silent !xset  led named 'Caps Lock'
        autocmd InsertLeave * :silent !xset -led named 'Caps Lock'
        autocmd VimLeave    * :silent !xset -led named 'Caps Lock'
    augroup END
endif
```

After sourcing `$MYVIMRC` or restarting `vim`, the <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> LED will light whenever `vim` is in insert mode, by whatever means. Hitting the lit <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> key will return `vim` to the normal mode.

On my [Varmilo](http://en.varmilo.com/) VA88M keyboard this LED is built into the <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> key, which results in a nice effect.

Answer (score 4):

> Unfortunately, explanations about how to accomplish this Vim feat (under GNU/Linux) are nowhere to be found.

You can craft your own solution, using building blocks.

Vim can execute external commands. Try `:!ls` if you are not familiar with this feature.

Vim can also map keys to other keys, or key sequences. If you are not familiar with this feature, try:

```
:noremap i iLOL
```

After having issued this mapping, every time you go into insert mode, Vim will insert LOL, as if you typed it.

The last building block you need is a command to control the lights on your keyboard. The command you need might differ from system to system. My keyboard does not have a caps lock light, for instance (Lenovo T440s). Instead I used the keyboard backlight. I recommend you create your own command, say, in your home directory, `~/light_on` and `~/light_off`. (Feel free to choose another path.)

Don't forget to `chmod +x lights_o*`.

Contents of `lights_on`:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo 2 | tee > /sys/class/leds/tpacpi\:\:kbd_backlight/brightness
```

Contents of `lights_off`:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo 0 | tee > /sys/class/leds/tpacpi\:\:kbd_backlight/brightness
```

These work for my computer. It may or may not work on yours. You should edit these files to your computer's requirements. Make sure you look into the directory `/sys/class/leds/`. There are other lights as well. Caution: In that directory `echo 0 > file` does not work. Instead you should use `echo 0 | tee > file`. I don't know why.

Now, you understandably need superuser rights to control the lights in this manner. In order to run these scripts, you need to `sudo ./lights_on` and then type the sudo password. This is inconvenient. (`xset` might not need sudo rights, see below.)

You can authorize users to run certain privileged commands without needing a password by editing `/etc/sudoers`. I did this by following https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/215412/allow-certain-guests-to-execute-certain-commands. I added lines 18 and 28. See image.

[image]

(Caution: I had to write line 28 after line 27 to get it working, unlike the instructions in the link.)

If you cannot get the `echo | tee` trick working, here's another suggestion: I have also come across `xset led on` and `xset led off`. Try if these work for you, or try to find out more on `xset`. (I personally could not get `xset` to control my keyboard lights.)

At this point you should be able to control your keyboard lights by `sudo ~/lights_on` and `sudo ~/lights_off`, without a sudo password.

Now you could do `:nnoremap i :!sudo ~/light_on<cr><cr>i`. But there is more than one way to enter insert mode - `i` `I` `a` `A` `o` `O` and maybe more. So instead you should use `autocmd`:

```
:autocmd! InsertEnter * execute ('!sudo ~/light_on &')
```

And of course, upon leaving the insert mode, the lights should go off:

```
:autocmd! InsertLeave * execute ('!sudo ~/light_off &')
```

You could add this to your vimrc once you are satisfied with the behavior.

Comment: Thank you for taking the effort in writing this somewhat long answer. As for writing to system devices, `echo 0 | sudo tee > …` is what you are looking for. This is [explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21765289/2192488). You are getting there through a `sudo` detour.